# Detecting uninitialized variables in gcc

Tags: gcc

The following (broken) example code scanf's an input string to an integer, but allow an empty string through to as 0:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int parse(const char *p)
{
    int value; // whoops! forgot to 0 here.
    if (*p && sscanf(p, "%d", &value) != 1)
        return -1;
    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *p = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "";
    int value = parse(p);
    printf("value = %d\n", value);
}
```

but it compiles clean with -Wall.

https://godbolt.org/z/sPbx99Ms5

but fails with obvious problems:

```
$ ./test 123
value = 123
$ ./test xxx
value = -1
$ ./test ""
value = 32765
```

I realise it's quite hard for it to work out that the scanf *might* not fill in a value as it
can't see the code, but is there a flag or a scanner I could run on a (large) body of code to try and find if there are places where uninitialized variables are being passed by pointer?

... even something that would just find all uninitialized variables would be useful.

Comment: clang catches it: https://godbolt.org/z/oEh4nnf3n  It's not so much about the passing by pointer, but rather that it notices that if `*p` is false then `sscanf` won't be called at all.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, how about this example: https://godbolt.org/z/odesqqdx9 which doesn't complain that 'v' is not initialised. compiled with clang though it seems to always be zerod. with g++ you get rnd()

Comment: Looks similar to [this gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19430).

Comment: it does! I've just tried the above example with (debian experimental) gcc-11 though and it's still silent.